# PHP: Passing Function return as a parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in one function and want to return `$dlm_download->the_download_link();` to the TellAFriend function. Just wanted to know what is the correct way of doing it.

```
 echo $dlm_download->the_download_link();  //  Displays correctly
 TellAFriend($dlm_download->the_download_link();); //  error


function TellAFriend($TellAFriendLink='null')
 echo $TellAFriendLink;
```

Comment: `NULL` shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: echo is not return...

Comment: PeeHaa -- I am not returning $downloadlink  Just passing it to a parameter. Used echo just to check whether it is being assigned any value or not.

Comment: I have no idea what the heck you're asking...

Comment: Mike-  Sorry if it is confusing. I will update it

Comment: Use `var_dump($downloadlink);` and share what it outputs.

Comment: Practically -  Sorry i have updated the question to make it more clear.  But var_dump($downloadlink); displays NULL

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `the_download_link()` function?

Comment: public function the_download_link() {
  echo $this->get_the_download_link();
 }

Comment: public function get_the_download_link() {
  $scheme   = parse_url( get_option( 'home' ), PHP_URL_SCHEME );
  $endpoint = ( $endpoint = get_option( 'dlm_download_endpoint' ) ) ? $endpoint : 'download';
  $ep_value = get_option( 'dlm_download_endpoint_value' );

  switch ( $ep_value ) {
   case 'slug' :
    $value = $this->post->post_name;
    break;
   default :
    $value = $this->id;
    break;
  }

Comment: if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
   $link = home_url( '/' . $endpoint . '/' . $value . '/', $scheme );
  } else {
   $link = add_query_arg( $endpoint, $value, home_url( '', $scheme ) );
  }

  if ( $this->version_id ) {

   if ( $this->has_version_number() ) {
    $link = add_query_arg( 'version', $this->get_file_version()->get_version_slug(), $link );
   } else {
    $link = add_query_arg( 'v', $this->version_id, $link );
   }
  }

  return apply_filters( 'dlm_download_get_the_download_link', esc_url_raw( $link ), $this, $this->version_id );
 }

Comment: @sonu769
Would be awesome if you could put the class assigned to $dlm_download, formatted, either hosted elsewhere or in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the class method you posted in your comment:

> public function the_download_link() { echo $this->get_the_download_link(); }

This is why you're getting null returned to your code here:

> $link = $dlm_download->the_download_link();

The function is echoing the link, not returning it. So the variable would get null. The class method should be:

```
public function the_download_link() { return $this->get_the_download_link(); }
```

Or just use

```
$link = $dlm_download->get_the_download_link();
```

And that should return the link to your variable opposed to echoing it and returning nothing.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks a lot. Practically...

Answer (score 0):

Set `$dlm_download->the_download_link()` to a variable and pass that to `TellAFriend()` function.

```
$link = $dlm_download->the_download_link();
TellAFriend($link);

function TellAFriend($TellAFriendLink = null) {
    echo $TellAFriendLink;
}
```

I also fixed some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: var_dump($link);  Dsiplays NULL

Comment: echo $dlm_download->the_download_link();  displays a link  http://example.com/download/000/

Comment: Where are you running `var_dump($link)`?

Comment: $link = $dlm_download->the_download_link();                                 var_dump($link);
TellAFriend($link);